# How to Prevent jquery.mousewheel.js from Loading on Pages in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, mousewheel

Ok, so I've managed to get horizontal scroll via mousewheel working for my my Wordpress site using the Expositio theme (http://wpshower.com/themes/expositio/)

This uses Brandon Aaron's Jquery-Mousewheel which can be found here : https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/zipball/master/ (for those of you who had difficulty finding a working link like I did!)

After this code in my Header.php :

```
        <?php
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

        if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
        wp_head();
    ?>
```

I've inserted this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/includes/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $('html, body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 90);
        event.preventDefault();
    })
});
</script>
```

Which works perfectly & looks great with this theme (I hope this information above is useful to a another newbie like me - the '90' denotes speed - I found the default 30 to be too slow a scroll for the content on my website)

However, I want the horizontal scrolling to *not* load for specific pages such as the 'About' etc. In fact, it could maybe work if this plugin was prevented from loading on *all* pages (since these don't have the horizontal layout that the rest of Expositio theme has)

Does anyone have any idea what code might work to make this possible? I want *posts* to load horizontal mousewheel scrolling, but not *pages* (or at least be able to exclude specific pages). I'd really appreciate any help - I'm fed up of floundering around in the dark! :)

Comment: Regarding your download difficulties, you shouldn't download the current master branch as you don't want to use a bleeding edge development version, but some of the [tagged versions](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/tags) or use the [jQuery plugin registry](http://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if(!is_page()) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/includes/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @Lull As you seem to be a new user, you might want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about) or read [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/224848) on how to accept an answer. ;-)