# How do I enable horizontal scrolling with the mouse wheel using Javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, scroll

I'm working with the Portra theme by WPShower: http://wpshower.com/demo/?preview_theme=portra and I want to be able to scroll horizontally using the mouse wheel instead of having to grab and drag the scroll bar.

I found what I think is the code and plugin link that will help me achieve this from another forum discussing a sister theme to Portra: [How to Prevent jquery.mousewheel.js from Loading on Pages in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458532/how-to-prevent-jquery-mousewheel-js-from-loading-on-pages-in-wordpress) but I don't know exactly where to paste the code within the php files (header.php or otherwise) in Wordpress.

I'd really appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You most definitely will not be using PHP. Its making it slower and it's pointless when you are able to use javascript. And to add the code into the php files, all you need to do is open them up in a txt editor and add in some script tags(outside the php code).    ...Another note, Why would you want to scroll horizontally, its not acceptable in web design(ugly). People are used to vertical. If you must, make sure you are not scrolling the entire webpage, only a section

Answer (score 1):

I would use jquery for that. Paste two script links in head section:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>
```

Then before `</body>` put:

```
<script>
  $("#element").mousewheel(function(event, delta) { // #element - your element id which has horizontal overflow
      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
      event.preventDefault();
   });
</script>
```

Tried myself, worked well. Download link for jquery and mousewheel: http://www.mediafire.com/download/x6vwofzc0x5aeel/jquery_+_mousewheel.zip